# Birthdays in the scope of java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, localdate, java-time

I'm trying to select birthdays (independent of the year) within a Collection of `java.time.LocalDate` . Why LocalDate ? because this type seems the best for birthday.

**Let's say I want to filter the birthdays between March 6 and April 30 irrespective of the year.
How to do this ?**

If I were to do it, I would replace the year in LocalDate  and use the method `isAfter` and `isBefore`. 
The fact that I have to change the year is just a plain hack. Or I  used the wrong data type (LocalDate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rather use the type [MonthDay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) which is the "date-without-year" and which is also comparable and offers methods like `isAfter()` or `isBefore()`. Furthermore, a `MonthDay` can be extended to a `LocalDate` using the method `atYear(int)`.

If you insist on `LocalDate` then you should only use leap years because otherwise the 29th of February would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<LocalDate> birthdays = Arrays.asList(
        LocalDate.of(1990, Month.JANUARY, 5),
        LocalDate.of(1992, Month.MARCH, 7),
        LocalDate.of(1995, Month.MAY, 5));
MonthDay filterFrom = MonthDay.of(Month.MARCH, 6);
MonthDay filterTo = MonthDay.of(Month.APRIL, 30);

List<LocalDate> filteredDates = birthdays.stream()
        .filter(date -> {
            MonthDay md = MonthDay.from(date);
            return md.compareTo(filterFrom) >= 0 && md.compareTo(filterTo) <= 0;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(filteredDates);
```